# Python Bottle framework error 500: can't find template in Daemon mode

Tags: python, wsgi, bottle

I'm currently working on a simple webapp in Python using the [bottle framework](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/index.html). Here is my app structure:

**Structure**

```
lib
    - bottle.py
    - bottledaemon.py
    - lockfile.py
    - __init__.py
view
    - dashboard.tpl
run.py
```

**And here is my run.py code:**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from lib.bottle import route, template, run, debug, request, static_file
from lib.bottledaemon import daemon_run

debug(mode=True)

@route('/')
def show_index():

    return template('dashboard')

# If the following line is enabled, the server will start in non-Daemon mode.
#run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80, debug=True)

# If the following lines are enabled, the server will start in Daemon mode.
if __name__ == "__main__":
  daemon_run()
```

So I want the WSGI server to run in a daemon by passing it to the [bottle daemon script](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BottleDaemon/0.1.0).

**The problem**

When run the code non-daemonized it works. It shows me the correct template and in the CLI I can see the HTTP requests.

When I run the same code in daemonized mode however, it does start as a daemon so that works fine, but it can't find the template anymore. It shows me this error msg:

> Error: 500 Internal Server Error
>
> Sorry, the requested URL 'HERE IS MY WEBSITE URL' caused an error:
>
> Template 'template' not found.

So it looks like the file path of the .tpl file can't be found anymore when I start the webserver in daemonized mode. I've tried a lot of things already but I can't figure it out and I would like to keep the path dynamic. Any suggestions guys?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is probably a path issue, I was able to recreate it and fix it by manually adding the path of the view folder to bottles TEMPLATE_PATH list.

```
from bottle import route, template, run, debug, request, static_file, TEMPLATE_PATH
from bottledaemon import daemon_run

import os

TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "view")))

# rest of script
```

Edit:

Traced it to the root of the problem, it is a path issue for sure. `bottledaemon` imports `daemon` and runs `DaemonContext` which by default changes the working directory to `'/'`and `bottledaemon` does not override that like it should. So when bottle looks for a relitive path of the `view` folder, it's actually looking for '/view' on the root of the system.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 6, in <module>
    TEMPLATE_PATH.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file_
_), "view")))
NameError: name 'TEMPLATE_PATH' is not defined

Comment: Look at the top line, you need to add it to your import list

Comment: Thanks mate! Now the daemon starts again. Still the same 500 error tho. Is there a static path somewhere that I have to insert in the code you provided?

Comment: Should not have to, what is odd is the error you provide says it's looking for`'Template 'template'` whereas you specify `dashboard`. I would suggest renaming `dashboard.tpl` to `template.tpl` to see if that displays it for now.

Comment: Thank you so mutch this fixed it!! I was stuck on this for hours. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it's working, best of luck with the rest of your project!